# How can I make a scroll content for my comment?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make it "scrollable" when the user add a comment.

this is the css code:

```
.contenu_post{

    width:700px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:white;
    float:right;
    margin-right:80px;
    margin-top:20px;
    text-align:center;

    box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px #333;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px #333;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px #333;    
}
```

And my html code:[html code source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYN2M.png)

its the the class "post_user" in the html code I want to be "scrollable"

Thanks you for both of you! :)

Comment: add `overflow-y: scroll`? If that doesn't work, post your HTML, too.

Comment: there's no code to support any tags here, other than css, which automatically makes the question unclear, and too broad. Edit: now the php tag was removed only in an edit.

Comment: I post my html code for help.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Michael Coker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1123505/michael-coker) said, use `overflow-y: scroll;` on the content you want scrollable. And as [Fred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii) said, it's pretty hard to know exactly where that should go without more information about your markup structure.

edited

Comment: *"Like Fred said"* - About missing HTML and the JS tag ;-) Yet, let's not leave "Michael Coker" out of it neither; he's the one that it should be credited to ;-)